# Google App Actions Custom Intents in Flutter App (Internal testing)

Tags: android, flutter, app-actions

I have a Flutter App and successfully implemented BII (actions.intent.OPEN_APP_FEATURE)

However, when I try to implement custom-intents on my Flutter App, it does not work on device. It can works on Google Assistant Plugin though.

My app is uploaded as Internal Release only.
Does Custom Intents works when app is in Internal Release only?

Or there is something I missed out? My shortcuts file as below:

```
     <shortcuts
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<capability android:name="actions.intent.OPEN_APP_FEATURE">
        <intent
            android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW"
            android:targetClass="com.huislaw.cafe_app.MainActivity"
            android:targetPackage="com.huislaw.cafe_app">
            <parameter
                android:name="feature"
                android:key="feature" />
        </intent>
    </capability>
    <shortcut
        android:enabled="false"
        android:shortcutId="feature_one"
        android:shortcutShortLabel="@string/label_feature_one">
        <capability-binding android:key="actions.intent.OPEN_APP_FEATURE">

            <parameter-binding
                android:key="feature"
                android:value="@array/feature_one_synonyms" />
        </capability-binding>
    </shortcut>
    <shortcut
        android:enabled="false"
        android:shortcutId="feature_two"
        android:shortcutShortLabel="@string/label_feature_two">
        <capability-binding android:key="actions.intent.OPEN_APP_FEATURE">
            <parameter-binding
                android:key="feature"
                android:value="@array/feature_two_synonyms" />
        </capability-binding>
    </shortcut>
    <capability
        android:name="custom.actions.intent.STOCK_AVAILABILITY"
        app:queryPatterns="@array/StockAvailabilityQueries">
        <intent
            android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW"
            android:targetClass="com.huislaw.cafe_app.MainActivity"
            android:targetPackage="com.huislaw.cafe_app">
            <parameter
                android:name="store_location"
                android:key="store_location" />
        </intent>
    </capability>
    <shortcut
        android:shortcutId="STOCK_AVAILABILITY"
        android:shortcutShortLabel="@string/stockAvailabilityShort">
        <capability-binding android:key="custom.actions.intent.STOCK_AVAILABILITY">
            <parameter-binding
                android:key="store_location"
                android:value="@array/storeLocation"/>
        </capability-binding>
    </shortcut>
</shortcuts>
```

My Arrays:

```
 <string-array name="StockAvailabilityQueries">
        <item>Lookup stock in $text1</item>
        <item>Find this item at $text1</item>
        <item>Stock check for $text1</item>
        <item>Is this item in stock at $text1</item>
        <item>Find this item at $text1</item>
    </string-array>
```

Comment: managed to solve? I'm having the same problem